# What is the SyntaxError in the a "def" line in a python script?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run the follow python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#Author Jared Adolf-Bryfogle



#Python Imports
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union
#Append Python Path
p = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]+"/src"
sys.path.append(p) #Allows all modules to use all other modules, without needing to update pythonpath

#Project Imports
from pic2.modules.chains.ProposedIgChain import ProposedIgChain
from pic2.modules.chains.IgChainSet import IgChainSet
from pic2.modules.chains.IgChainFactory import IgChainFactory
from pic2.modules.chains.AbChainFactory import AbChainFactory

from pic2.tools.fasta import *


class IgClassifyFASTA:
    """
    Identify CDRs from a Fasta File
    """
    def __init__(self, fasta_path: Union[Path, str]):
        self.fasta_path = str(fasta_path)
        self.outdir = os.getcwd()
        self.outname = "classified"
        self.fasta_paths = split_fasta_from_fasta(os.path.abspath(self.fasta_path), "user_fasta_split_"+self.outname, self.outdir)


    def __exit__(self):
        for path in self.fasta_paths:
            if os.path.exists(path):
                os.remove(path)

    def set_output_path(self, outdir: Union[Path, str]):
        self.outdir = str(outdir)

    def set_output_name(self, outname: Union[Path, str]):
        self.outname = str(outname)
```

My python version is 3.8, and the pic2 is a conda env. I get the the following error:

```
File "IgClassifyFASTA.py", line 29
    def __init__(self, fasta_path:Union[Path, str]):
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I cannot figure out what's wrong with this line. Could you kindly give me some hint what's the wrong lying in? I will appreciate any help.

Best regards!

Comment: The only way that I can reproduce your error is if I try to run it in a Python 2.7 interpreter, which doesn't support the kind of type hints that you are using.

Comment: Can you place a `print(sys.version)` somewhere before your `class` definition and post the output?

Comment: @Axe319 print(sys.version) doesn't give any output when placed before the class definition. The script gave the same error message as before.

Comment: Are you sure? It should print something like `3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]`. At the very least it prints something. If it doesn't, you're probably not running the script you think you're running.

Comment: I am sure that I am running the exact script.